# In SQL Selecting Specific Dates(Recurring)

Tags: sql, mysql

How can I efficiently retrieve dates falling on both Mondays and Sundays from a date column over the past year using MySQL?

My current approach involves manually selecting these dates, which is time-consuming. Is there a more streamlined method to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1):

How about a combination of date range checking and `DAYOFWEEK()`?

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE mydatecolumn BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND CURDATE()
AND DAYOFWEEK(mydatecolumn) IN (1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM have
WHERE DAYOFWEEK(date) IN (1, 2)
  AND date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR AND CURDATE()
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select dates that fall on Mondays and Sundays from the past year in MySQL using a query with the `DATE` and `DAYOFWEEK` functions.

```
SELECT date_column
  FROM your_table_name
 WHERE date_column BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR AND CURDATE()  -- Select dates from the past year
   AND DAYOFWEEK(date_column) IN (1, 2);      -- Filter for Mondays (2) and Sundays (1)
```